# Sending potentially large messages over Netty in parallel

Tags: java, netty

I want to implement a server/client application using Netty. As an example, suppose it needs to upload and download files and receive notifications when new files are uploaded. The problem is that the client must receive notifications even while downloading (or uploading) a file. I can see a few options:

1. Only send small messages over TCP containing URLs to files, download and upload over HTTP.
2. Open several parallel connections over TCP, using one for small messages and one for large (or one for each large message).
3. Write a chunking handler which automatically splits messages into chunks under 64Kb (e.g.) and allows chunks from different messages to be interleaved. From documentation, it seems [`ChunkedWriteHandler`](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.html) does *not* do this.

What I like in option 3 is that the client only needs to authenticate once, there is no possibility of one connection breaking while another is maintained, etc. But is it reasonable? And if yes, does such a solution already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunks are nothing but http messages, try to use a socket client which buffers then writes your file to netty chunk by chunk in one single connection, then use netty http chunk aggregator handler to decode the chunks. The client implementation is pretty simple. Most of the server side implementation can be found under org.jboss.netty.example.http.upload .

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of both client and server, use websockets. You are free to invent your own file transer protocol on top of it, including notifications and whatnot. Kermit goes websocket ;-)